# How to limit the amount of rows in a VueJS table

Tags: html, vue.js

I have this table

```
 <table class="table"> 
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>{{ i18n('Date') }}</th>
                        <th>{{ i18n('Transaction Type') }}</th>
                        <th>{{ i18n('Starbucks Card') }}</th>
                        <th>{{ i18n('Card Type') }}</th>
                        <th>{{ i18n('Amount') }} (R$)</th>
                        <th>{{ i18n('Stars') }}</th>
                        <th>{{ i18n('Expiration of the Stars') }}</th>
                        <th>{{ i18n('Store') }}</th>
                        <th>{{ i18n('Product') }}</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody v-if="loading">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="9" class="loading"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tbody v-if=" ! loading && data.extract && ! data.extract.length">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="9" class="no-results">{{ i18n('No results found') }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tbody v-if=" ! loading &&  data.extract && data.extract.length" class="sf">               
                    <tr v-for="(item, k) in data.extract" v-bind:key="k">
                        <td>{{ formatDate(item.transactionDate) }}</td>
                        <td>{{ i18n(processDescription(item.typeDescription)) }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.starbucksCard }}</td>
                        <td>{{ i18n(item.cardType) }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.value }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.stars }}</td>
                        <td>{{ (item.expirationDate) ? formatDate(item.expirationDate) : ' - '}}</td>
                        <td>{{ (item.place) ? item.place : ' - ' }}</td>
                        <td v-if="!item.products || item.products.length == 0"> - </td>
                        <td v-if="item.products"> 
                            <div v-for="(prod,k) in item.products" v-bind:key="k">
                                - {{prod}}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

It is automatically populated with an object that comes from an endPoint, However, this element is very large, with more than 10000 thousand lines, in this case I need to limit the number of lines in the frontEnd. I looked in several places but I didn't find anything that could help.

Comment: You can try to use slice like this : `v-for="(item, k) in data.extract.slice(0, 5)"`  to limit it to the first 5 elements

Comment: Depending which api you are using, most likely it provides ability to either limit number of records in response, or allows pagination, this way your user wont have to download all these records in first place. Then if you need to display more records you can do infinite list - when user gets to end of list, more records get fetched), or provide normal pagination controls.